# bing maps RouteResponse.Results.RoutePath.Points = null?

Tags: wpf, bing-maps

I am having a little problem with my Bing Maps service. I want to draw a route in a WPF app. Its everithing working except when I read the RoutePath.Points from the Result . In the field Legs there are all the directions but in the RoutePath there arent any data.

This is weird. What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the problem. 
I need to define the options to routerequest bring the routePath with the points.

```
routeRequest.Options = new RouteOptions() { RoutePathType = RoutePathType.Points };
```

You can close this topic....